# mod_rewrite remove trailing slash not working in Laravel

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-3

I have the following code setup in my htaccess file for my Laravel 3 installation:

```
# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-z-]+)\.([0-9a-z-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove index.php from base URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which looks all well and good untill the first ReWrite condition is accessed.

Navagating to this url:

```
/information/
```

Redirects me to:

```
/home/xxx/Dropbox/Development/laravel/httpdocs/information
```

So the trailing slash is being removed, but it redirecting to the abolsute URL.

Why is it doing that? How do I fix it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `RewriteBase /` (or whatever the base URI should be) above all of your rules.

What's happening is that mod_rewrite tries to guess if the target of a rewrite rule is a URL path or a file path and it is guessing incorrectly that it's a file path and appends the incorrect base path.

Comment: Good call! :) I totally missed that :P