# Laravel 4.2 Trailing Slash leads to base uri

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem and I still can't fix that.
I know that there are similars question here on SO, but nothing of that worked.

I use restful controllers.
When I visit `http://localhost/project/public/subsite` it works.
But when I visit `http://localhost/project/public/subsite/` it redirects me to `http://localhost/subsite`

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] </IfModule>
```

I already tried solutions from these questions:
[laravel trailing Slashes redirect to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735527/laravel-trailing-slashes-redirect-to-localhost)
[mod_rewrite remove trailing slash not working in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097941/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-not-working-in-laravel)

But the problem remains the same.

Comment: _“This is my current htdocs file”_ – you mean `.htaccess` file, I suppose? And where is that `.htaccess` file located within your folder structure?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I mean .htaccess file - it's stored in /project/public/

Comment: That’s the problem then – when you configure rewriting in .htaccess context, the path to the directory of the .htaccess is already stripped off of the request URI when RewriteRules get to work – so your `^(.*)/$` only matches on `subsite/` in the first place. See if configuring a `RewriteBase` beforehand can fix that (not totally sure myself).

Comment: I already did that like in the other questions mentioned I linked in my question but the problem remains.

Comment: why dont you have the webroot pointing to the public folder ?

Comment: I can't. I'm not having the opportunity - easy said.

Comment: Well you could always try and simply give the path prefix `/project/public/` explicitly in your RewriteRule’s substitution part …

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteBase /project/public/

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

It worked for me to omit the slash that Cryode pointed to. Also be sure to clear your browser cache otherwise the changes may not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a RewriteBase:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/public/
```

Essentially, when you specify the beginning slash in your rewrite line:

```
#                   V----- This little guy
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

It says "go to this URL, starting from the root". Since your root is `http://localhost`, it starts from there, not from your project's root.